# Comparing a sequence of n characters in a hex-value

Tags: c, eclipse, compare, hex

I'm basicly trying to compare a token(string) with a hex-datatype!

Example:

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<string.h>

int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {

    char* token ="Hello";
    int hex = 0x2F;


    if(strncmp(token, "Hil", 3)==0){
        printf("Token founde"); //works!
    }else{
        printf("sorry seems to be the hardest word");
    }

}
```

This actually works, of course.
I'm comparing 2 strings with at least n charachters...no problem.

But now I want to do the same thing with a hex-value instead of a string!
Something like this:

```
 int hex = 0x2F;


    if(strncmp((char*)hex, "0x", 2)==0){
                printf("Token founde"); //works!
            }else{
                printf("sorry seems to be the hardest word");
            }

        }
```

Since strncmp compares strings only, I tried to cast the hex-value to a char*...
It doesn't work at all.

I've searched everywhere... even in my "The programming language C" book...but I can't figure out how to solve this problem.

In java, I'd use something like startsWith etc... but I don't know if there is a familiar function in c that could have the same effect.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Hm, I am not sure that this is what you want, but right now you are converting the **value** of hex to an (most certainly invalid) address. To do what you want to do you have to take the address: `strncmp((char*)&hex, "0x", 2)` but I cannot recommend that.

I suggest that you transform the hex into a string first and then compare:

```
char buf[256];
snprintf(buf, 256, "0x%x", hex);
if(strncmp(buf, "0x", 2)==0){
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use [sprintf](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/clibrary/cstdio/sprintf/):

```
char hexVal[3];
sprintf(hexVal, "%02X", hex);
if(strncmp(token, hexVal, 3)==0){
```